# jQuery ContextMenu by swisnl change text size or font

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I am using jQuery Context from swisnl, but I can't find any way around of changing the font or the font-size from css. I can only change it to Italics/Bold but not to a different font or size.

Those css changes only affect the icons and not the text itself.

Any ideas on how to change the text size/font?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find the font styles in the "theme.css" in the documentation > website > css folder.  The font family is set in the body. You could always overwrite it with a custom CSS called after the context menu loads.  The class you are looking at would be '.context-menu-item span'.

In your CSS it would be:

```
 .context-menu-item{font-family:Times New Roman}/*Seemed to work using Chrome inspector*/
```

If you want to target the specific element, the text is wrapped in a span.

```
.context-menu-item span{font-family:Times New Roman !important}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just if you're trying to styling an 'item type text' content, you can do it with events as following:

```js
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    items: {
      "textinput": {name: "Type something:", type: 'text', 
        events: {
          keydown: function(event) {
            $(this).css({"color":"magenta","font-size":"14px"});
            //$(this).parent().parent().css({"background":"green","font-size":"20px"});  //works too
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<button class="context-menu-one">Right click me</button>
```